# What function can plot the distribution on the Y axis of line chart in R?

Tags: r, plot, distribution

Please tell me in R, what function or package can plot the distribution of time series data on the Y axis of a line chart.

Such as the graphs below.

[image: Example]

Thank you for your any help.

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggExtra/versions/0.9/topics/ggMarginal

Comment: You can pass the y variables into `hist()` and it will create a histogram strictly of the values without regard for time.

Comment: @sconfluentus Unfortunately, `hist`  cannot be used to plot the density AND the trend of a variable. That is what OP asked.

Comment: I did not see that they wanted both, just that they wanted the density...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `ggplot2` and `patchwork`.

Start by loading the libraries:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
```

Now let's create some sample data to use:

```
df <- airquality
df$Date <- seq(from = as.Date("1973-05-01"), 
               to   = as.Date("1973-09-30"), 
               by   = "1 day")
```

We can make the density plot like this

```
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(y = Temp)) +
  geom_density(fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2, color = "blue") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_line(color = "white"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(color = "white"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(color = "white"),
        axis.line.x = element_line(color = "white")
        )
```

And the main time series plot like this:

```r
p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(Date, Temp)) +
  geom_line(color = "blue") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#fef8d6"),
        axis.ticks.length.y = unit(0, "pt"),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

To draw them we can do:

```
p1 + p2 + plot_layout(widths = c(1, 8))
```

[image]